# how to convert all the websites which are coming in python shell in hyperlink?

Tags: python-2.7, hyperlink

"""using BeautifulSoup4 and google search to search"""

```
query = "stackoverflow"

for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=1, pause=2):

print(j)
```